# 'int' object has no attribute 'uniform'

Tags: python, class

1) I'm trying to calculate the area, however, I'm having this error.
AttributeError: 'area' object has no attribute 'radius'
Kindly help me out.

Thanks in advance.

```
import math, random

class area():
    def __init__(self,radius, length, breath, height, base):
        if radius==0 and breath!=0:
                self.radius=random.uniform(1.1, 9.5)
                self.length=random.uniform(10.5,15.5)
                self.breath=random.uniform(15,20)
                self.height=random.uniform(20,25)
                self.base=random.uniform(26,32)
        elif length==0 and heigh!=0: 
                self.radius=random.uniform(1.1, 9.5)
                self.length=length
                self.breath=random.uniform(15,20)
                self.height=height
                self.base=base
        elif height==0 and base!=0:
                self.radius=radius
                self.length=random.uniform(1.1, 9.5)
                self.breath=breath
                self.height=random.uniform(1.1, 9.5)
                self.base=base    

    def areaofcircle(self):
        return math.pi* (self.radius**2)
    def areaoftriangl(self):
        return 0.5*self.height*self.base
    def areaofrectangle(self):
        return self.length*self.breath

areas=[]
for i in range(0,10):
    c=area(1,3,5,0,0)
    areas.append(c)

for c in areas:
    print( "Area of Circle:",c.areaofcircle(),\
           "Area of Triangle:", c.areaoftriangl(),\
           "Area of Rectangle:",c.areaofrectangle(),\
        )
```

Comment: `c.areaofcircle` -> `c.areaofcircle()`

Comment: Well Thanks, Man but what about using with Uniform??

Comment: Please update the question with the full Traceback so we can tell which line is being complained about.

Comment: 1. I'm not a man. 2. I have no idea why you are using uniform. The error is straightforward - int doesn't have any "uniform" attribute and the values you need are literally just normal integers.